# How to extract Decoded data from a list?

Tags: python, list, image, barcode-scanner, nested-lists

```
[[Decoded(data=b'AZ:HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY', rect=Rect(left=37, top=152, width=94, height=97)),Decoded(data=b'AZ:1EBWZS6F15BDFNK7SK5Y5N3X5U', rect=Rect(left=2616, top=1414, width=108, height=122))], [Decoded(data=b'AZ:9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI', rect=Rect(left=32, top=191, width=90, height=88)),Decoded(data=b'AZ:1EBWZS6F15BDFNK7SK5Y5N3X5U', rect=Rect(left=2616, top=1414, width=108, height=122))], [Decoded(data=b'AZ:6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M', rect=Rect(left=48, top=183, width=88, height=89))], [Decoded(data=b'AZ:XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ', rect=Rect(left=73, top=121, width=91, height=94))]]
```

I have a lists of lists like above, the above list is named `result`.

Now I want to extract only `AZ:HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY` , from all lists from the list .

I have tried

#### loop over the detected barcodes

```
for barcode in result:

    # the barcode data is a bytes object so if we want to draw it on
    # our output image we need to convert it to a string first
    barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
```

But I'm getting `list object has no attribute "data "`, so I'm confused to how only extract important info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, the barcode data is nested inside a single element list, so you would have to take care of that during list creation, or correctly address index 0 of the nested list, with `[0]`:

```
data_list = list()
for entry in result:
    for barcode in entry:
        data_list.append(barcode.data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: It works great , I was missing the data_list part . Thanks for your help

Comment: When in the result lsit , theirs a empty row , I'm getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 57, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
 error

Comment: What shall i do when in  a single row , their are 2 or multiple cases of the AZ code ??  The above code works well when theirs only a single AZ code per row in the list

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable I'm getting above error while using the code

Comment: It sounds like your result list has mixed types in it. You may want to look at the code generating it to make sure you have consistent inputs

Comment: Thanks for the help . I was able to complete a major step in my project because of you. I'm really hppy and would like to thank be you